# Should we prefer Java 8 language / API over Java 6 and 7?

Tags: discussion, documentation, language-versions

Java 8 has been out for some time. Actually, it is currently the only supported version of Java if you don't count the Java 7 extended support (which most of us don't enjoy).

It seems strange to me that many examples in the Java language still prefer Java 6/7 syntax, even if there is a better alternative available.

Should we edit examples so that the later / better versions of the API are shown first? Currently most examples seem to show the old API's first and then show the Java 8 compatible version, if it is shown at all.

Comment: Oh yeah, related [this question about Q/A and Java 8](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296293/should-i-use-java-8-in-my-answers-to-version-agnostic-java-questions), maybe useful in forming an opinion. And you can of course discuss [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118054/java-documentation) as well, if you want to chat about it a bit first.

Comment: <!-- if version [geq 8.0] --> Java 8 <!-- end if version --> <!-- if version [lt 8.0] --> Java pre-8 <!--- end if version -->

Comment: @Braiam Ah, that seems worthwhile. That's for code segments only I suppose, or is it more generic?

Comment: The code is meant to be used in the editor, the topic has other UI for it.

Answer (score 5):

In general, try to use code which is supported through all versions still getting normal updates. [normal == not only security fixes] Put this one first in any case. It's weird to first see something what *won't* work for me and then I'll have to scroll down to see if anything working is there.

Where it is impossible to express code in the same way for different versions, prefer the newer version (and trail with the older one eventually).

In case the newer version is significantly better (readability etc.), but there is an easy way for expressing it working in both versions, feel free to trail with the improved example.

---

Yes, Java 8 is out for 2 years. But there are many targets still having the older version. Just as you also probably have to maintain code written the older way. And Java 7 still has "premier support", which is normal updates, just not for everyone...

If there is only Java 8 code, this is potentially confusing to users [doesn't work here; "WTF?"; ...].

I realize that the Java 8 way is sometimes significantly easier. For Q&A, I'd absolutely go with 8 unless otherwise requested as it primarily is targeting the OP (who also can then ask for a downgrade). However in documentation it's not obvious to ask someone for "give me the Java 7 code".

Comment: This would also be a great situation to use the code-switching tabs when they become available in the future - it might be more work to maintain multiple versions of examples, but at least it will be clearer which Java version the code is meant for.

Comment: Java 8's introduction of lambdas moved it towards a more functional and descriptive way of programming, which in turn allows people to program with less moving parts (see https://twitter.com/mfeathers/status/29581296216). I agree with the OP and think it's about time we started giving examples in Java 8 if they make the code simpler and more clear.

Comment: @uzilan As said, I know that _Java 8 is significantly easier_ [easier is maybe the wrong word, but makes code easier to read]. I'm all in favor of _also_ giving the Java 8 syntax.